# TestFlight App shows wrong SDK Version

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm using the TestFlight App to distribute my application over the air and therefore included the SDK version 1.2 into my app.

When I'm trying to upload my app using the desktop application it shows the wrong SDK Version (1.1) instead of 1.2.

Edit: It also seems, that it isn't just an information issue. It really is SDK Version 1.1 since it doesn't seem to support the new App Tokens (Sessions aren't displayed etc.) but I fetched the new version from the TestFlight Webpage and included it in my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Greetings

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to get TestFlight SDK using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/), it's fast and easy, takes care of the dependencies and settings, and let's you focus on the proper coding. 
The website has pretty straight forward info on how to set it up, but I wrote a [tutorial](http://amokafullofstuff.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/cocoapods/) about it.

To get the pod for TestFlightSDK you'll just need to add to your `Podfile` this line:

```
pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 1.2'
```

TestFlight is now part of the workspace, so it must be imported this way:

```
#import <TestFlight.h>
```

You should be good to go with CocoaPods, but here are some possible things to try out, if you haven't yet:

- Try an upload via the web interface instead of the desktop app
- Check the files you've added to the project, maybe you picked them from the wrong version folder
- Go over the [documentation for v1.2](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.2/) again, you could have missed a step
- [Download the SDK](https://www.testflightapp.com/sdk/download/) again, the UI of the website is not so clear, you could have picked the wrong one.

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay. I installed CocoaPods and opened my project using the workspace-file CP created for me. But now there a several errors that are displayed: Use of undeclared identifier TestFlight.h

Comment: Adding the header file to my Prefix.pch shows that error:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from: .. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 .. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Wait! I had this error message during the installation: [!] The target `SampleApp [Debug - Release]' overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS' build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.

Comment: Sorry, should have added this as well. TestFlight is now part of the workspace, so you have to import it this way `#import <TestFlight.h>`

Comment: I have done this. I added #import <TestFlight.h> in my Prefix.pch, but the compiler time error remains...: http://pastebin.com/ckHN9ZxK

Comment: Mmm... is libTestFlight.a still in your project "Link Binary With Libraries" list? If so take it away

Comment: I removed the old TestFlight files completely from my project. Could  that error cause the problem, that I've got while installing cocoapod? [!] The target `SampleApp [Debug - Release]' overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS' build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)' flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: I'm almost out of answers sorry... What's listed under Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths? My project has a long list, but they're only Pod related, in fact clicking on it I get `${PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}`. Maybe it's still trying to look for TestFlight static lib in there.

BTW there seem to some issues with that particular list of flags, see [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/593)

Comment: :( Out of answers. Try with some classic last resource: Clean / Quit and reopen Xcode / run `pod install` again. Sorry...

Comment: It didn't help. Thanks anyway for wasting your time with me. I will write an E-Mail to the TestFlight team in order to ask them why it doesn't work using the classic way.

Comment: @Phil, you need to make sure the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` settings from the `Pods.xcconfig` file are being used, which is what the message was warning about. Look for `Other Linker Flags` in your app target’s build settings and either remove the value if you don’t need it anymore, or add the `$(inherited)` flag.

Comment: @alloy That was special here. In the Debug and Release configuration this field was blank but still bold in Xcode. How can that be?

Comment: @Phil If it’s bold then the value is explicitly override to be blank. Highlight the line and press backspace to remove it.